# goessner json path non-recursive expression

Tags: jsonpath

What should be the Goesnner json path expression if I want to read only the parent id-Property and not the read all the child id-property recursively

Here's the example json that I am trying to parse :

```
[{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Abhishek",
    "Partners": [
        {
            "Id": 4,
            "Name": "COMPANION"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Id": 8,
    "name": "Dice Operations",
    "Partners": []
 }]
```

I would like to get the output of 1 and 8. But I keep getting the id 4 included. Here are the expressions that I have tried at [curiousconcept](http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/#) :

1. $.[0].Id
2. $.[*].Id
3. $..Id

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's supposed to be :  `$.*.Id`